# Browser interpreting everything after PHP -> symbol as text

Tags: php, html, css, apache, phpmailer

I'm just beginning to test [the PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) as documented on GitHub, as I'm having problems with the poorly-functioning mail() function sending email to my gmail account.

When I run the sample code, my browser is interpreting everything after the first -> as text, not PHP. I'm running Aptana 3/Xampp Apache Web Server. I'm not sure what would cause this and internet searches have been unhelpful.

Comment: You need to post your relevant PHP

Comment: It's the PHP documented in the GitHub link

Comment: Did you try all of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page

Comment: It just sounds like you don't have PHP configured? Can you run anything at all?

Comment: Went through the stackoverflow list as posted by Josh Purdy. I had already went through this and had set up PHP, but it turns out Aptana was using different run configurations that I had initially set up. Go figure. I am still very new to Aptana. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to put this in other something.php then :

```
<?php
include(something.php);
?>
```